# upload images to facebook then show it

Tags: php, html, facebook

I have an image uploader that works inside a facebook app

```
$image=clean($_FILES['image']['name']);
echo '<h1>Got it</h1>'.$image;
    //if it is not empty
    if (isset($_FILES))
    {
    //get the original name of the file from the clients machine
        $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
            echo '<h1>Got it 2</h1>'.$filename;

    //get the extension of the file in a lower case format
        $extension = getExtension($filename);

        $extension = strtolower($extension);
    //if it is not a known extension, we will suppose it is an error and 
        // will not  upload the file,  
    //otherwise we will do more tests

     if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension !=
     "png") && ($extension != "gif")) 
            {
            //print error message
                echo '<h1>Unknown extension!</h1>'.$filename.'hi';
                $errors=1;
            }
            else
            {
    //get the size of the image in bytes
     //$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] is the temporary filename of the file
     //in which the uploaded file was stored on the server
     $size=filesize($_REQUEST['image']['tmp_name']);

    //compare the size with the maxim size we defined and print error if bigger
    if ($size > MAX_SIZE*1024)
    {
        echo '<h1>You have exceeded the size limit!</h1>';
        $errors=1;
    }

    //we will give an unique name, for example the time in unix time format
    $image_name=time().'.'.$extension;
    //the new name will be containing the full path where will be stored (images 
    //folder)
    $newname="images/".$image_name;
    //we verify if the image has been uploaded, and print error instead
    $copied = copy($_REQUEST['image']['tmp_name'], $newname);
    if (!$copied) 
    {
    echo '<h1>Copy unsuccessfull!</h1>';
    $errors=1;
    $newname="copy";
}}}
```

now i wanna show these images in a div right beside the uploader how do i post the images that have been uploaded by the users

Comment: if(!copied){}else{..<div><img src='<?php echo $newname; ?>' ></div>}

Comment: Great thx (i just took it over from some of our programmers) im just doing the markup